# Using Oauth2 with scope, error - "Depends" has no attribute "query" - FastAPI

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, scope, fastapi, depends

**authentication.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from fastapi import  Depends , HTTPException, status, Security
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, SecurityScopes
from jose import JWTError, jwt
from auth.schemas import TokenData, UserBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from db.database import get_db
from pydantic import ValidationError
from db.models import UserModel


SECRET_KEY = '7f0ef2549adac85716db6ca433a44c79021e829c8c4dd8e7d9363eb9fc800e73'
ALGORITHM = 'HS256'
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login",
                                     scopes={"admin":"create content", "user":"interact with content"}
                                     )


def get_user(email: str,db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    user = db.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.email == email).first()
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, 
                            details=f"User with email: {email} not found")
    return user


async def get_current_user(
    security_scopes: SecurityScopes, token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)
):
    if security_scopes.scopes:
        authenticate_value = f'Bearer scope="{security_scopes.scope_str}"'
    else:
        authenticate_value = f"Bearer"
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": authenticate_value},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_scopes = payload.get("scopes", [])
        token_data = TokenData(scopes=token_scopes, username=username)
    except (JWTError, ValidationError):
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(email=token_data.email)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    for scope in security_scopes.scopes:
        if scope not in token_data.scopes:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="not enough permission",
                headers={"WWW-Authenticate": authenticate_value},
            )
    return user
    

def get_current_active_user(
    current_user:UserBase = Security(get_current_user, scopes=["admin"])):
    if not current_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user


def create_access_token(data:dict):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode,SECRET_KEY,algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt

def verify_token(token:str,credentials_exception):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token,SECRET_KEY,algorithms=ALGORITHM)
        email:str = payload.get("sub")
        if email is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(email=email)
        return token_data
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
```

**login**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends,HTTPException,status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, OAuth2PasswordBearer
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from db.models import UserModel
from db.database import get_db
from . import hashing
from auth.oauth import create_access_token
from .hashing import get_password_hash
from .schemas import UserBase

router = APIRouter(tags=['authentication'])


@router.post('/login')
async def login(request:OAuth2PasswordRequestForm=Depends(),db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    user = db.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.email == request.username).first()
    
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail="Invalid Credentials")
    
    if not hashing.verify_password(request.password,user.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,detail="Invalid Password")
    
    access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub":user.username,"scopes":request.scopes})
    return {"access_token":access_token,"token_type":"bearer"}

@router.post('/register')
async def register(request:UserBase,db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    new_user = UserModel(
        email = request.email,
        username = request.username,
        password = get_password_hash(request.password),
    )
    db.add(new_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_user)
    return new_user
```

**endpoints**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, Security
from auth.oauth import get_current_active_user
from routers.schemas import BikeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from db.database import get_db
from db.models import BikeModel
from .crud import add_bike
from auth.schemas import UserBase

router = APIRouter(
    prefix='/bike',
    tags = ['bike']
)

@router.post('/add')
def add_bike(request:BikeBase,user:UserBase=Depends(get_current_active_user),db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    
    bike = db.query(BikeModel).filter(BikeModel.model==request.model).first()
    if bike is None:
        return add_bike(request,user)
    if request.model in bike:
        raise Exception("Bike Model Already present")
    
    return add_bike(request,user)
        
@router.get('/check')
def check(user:UserBase=Security(get_current_active_user, scopes=["admin"])):
    return {"data":"scope working"}
```

```
def add_bike(request:BikeBase,user=Security(get_current_active_user, scopes=["admin"]),db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    new_bike = BikeBase(
            brand = request.brand.lower(),
            model = request.model.lower(),
            price = request.price,
            mileage = request.mileage,                
            max_power = request.max_power,
            rating = request.rating
            )
    db.add(new_bike)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_bike)
    return new_bike
```

On the `@router.post('/add')` getting the error:

```
File "/home/raj/code/bike-forum-fastapi/./auth/oauth.py", line 24, in get_user
    user = db.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.email == email).first()
AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'
```

When i change some endpoints to async the error changes something with coroutine, i cant remember how to produce it

`@router.check('/check')` endpoint works fine with scope and permission, but produces error at `@router.post('/add')`

i new to fastapi, the auth code is directly copied from fastapi-docs, but theres a hardcoded fake database for get_user in docs, i cant figure how to do it with a real database

Comment: You can't call `get_user` as a regular function and expect `Depends` to fill in any dependencies for you. The only time that happens is if it's part of another dependency (i.e. included through another `Depends` call from the view function). Use regular parameters if you're going to call it in any normal way.

Comment: @MatsLindh how can i query from the database without dependency injection in `get_user`, is there any other way ??, i cant find one

Comment: Add db = Depends(...) to your get_current_user function signature (where dependencies _gets_ resolved since it's used as a dependency), then send that `db` as an argument to `get_user`.

Comment: @MatsLindh followed these steps, now im getting a exception error  `could not validate credentials`  from get_current_user

Comment: It seems like you trigger that error before you even reach `get_user`, so I'd start debugging what you're actually sending to your get_current_user function